# Getting only matched part of the string in R

Tags: r, string

Is there a function in R that matches regexp and returns only the matched parts? 
Something like `grep -o`, so:

```
> ogrep('.b.',c('abc','1b2b3b4'))
[[1]]
[1] abc

[[2]]
[1] 1b2 3b4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably give Gabor Grothendieck the check for writing the gsubfn package:

```
 require(gsubfn)
#Loading required package: gsubfn
 strapply(c('abc','1b2b3b4'), ".b.", I)

#Loading required package: tcltk
#Loading Tcl/Tk interface ... done
[[1]]
[1] "abc"

[[2]]
[1] "1b2" "3b4"
```

This just applies the identity function , I, to the matches of the pattern.

Comment: The usage of Tk regexp is quite strange, but I liked it.

Comment: It is really an amazing package. I will have been twisting my head around a matching problem that I thought had multiple levels, and Gabor will whip out his Swiss Army multi-scalpel-screwdriver and do it in one line.  My memory of the last time I looked at the full list of gsubfn functions was that it only had two, but it seems to have doubled in size since it now has 4.

Comment: I would expect 2b3 to be present, too, but that doesn't seem to be the case. What's up with that?

Comment: I can see the point but I do not think one generally would want to have overlapping allowed in the matching situation. Consider this:   strapply("<B>Billions</B> and <B>Billions</B> and <B>Billions</B> of suns", "<B>.*?</B>", I)  ... I don't think you want all the possible overlapping matches and that doesn't seem to be how regex systems have been designed.

Comment: Just a few small points to add to this: 1. Regarding the comment on Tk regexp, gsubfn uses tcl regexp expressions by default if the R installation has tcltk capability but also supports R and perl regexp.  Use engine = "R" or perl = TRUE, respectively.   2.  Regarding I, note that I is actually the AsIs function.  The identity function in R is just: identity.  3. In this case one could actually omit the third arg: strapply(c('abc','1b2b3b4'), ".b.") .  4. If you want overlapping matches try this: strapply(c('abc','1b2b3b4'), ".b(?=.)")

Comment: My point #4 in the last comment was actually deficient because it did not return the third character in the match.  Try this instead: strapply(c('abc','1b2b3b4'), "(.b)(?=(.))", paste0, perl = TRUE)

Answer (score 8):

Try `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(c('abc','1b2b3b4'), '.b.')
# [[1]]
# [1] "abc"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "1b2" "3b4"
```

Answer (score 7):

I can't believe nobody ever mentioned `regmatches`!

```
x <- c('abc','1b2b3b4')
regmatches(x, gregexpr('.b.', x))

# [[1]]
# [1] "abc"

# [[2]]
# [1] "1b2" "3b4"
```

It makes me wonder, didn't `regmatches` exist two and half years ago?

Answer (score 5):

You need to combine gregexpr with substring, I reckon:

```
> s = c('abc','1b2b3b4')
> m = gregexpr('.b.',s)
> substring(s[1],m[[1]],m[[1]]+attr(m[[1]],'match.length')-1)
[1] "abc"
> substring(s[2],m[[2]],m[[2]]+attr(m[[2]],'match.length')-1)
[1] "1b2" "3b4"
```

The returned list 'm' has the start and lengths of matches. Loop over s to get all the substrings.

Comment: +1 because it seems the fastest solution, but I'm looking for simplest this time.